# How do I make a GATT server's read characteristic editable?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

Im working on making a GATT server that can be connected to by a client application, that will eventually send data to said client. the way I understand it, is that the only value the client can see is the Read characteristic, the characteristic that is advertised. The issue im having is how do I change what value of that advertised read characteristic.

Here is the full repository im working from: https://github.com/josipx/Jenx.Bluetooth.GattServer

This is the specific method that is called on to create the read characteristic and I believe the key to fixing this issue may lie in it.

```
public async Task<bool> AddReadCharacteristicAsync(Guid characteristicId, string characteristicValue, string userDescription)
        {
            
            
            count++;
            
            characteristicValue = "This is the value seen by the client";
            await _logger.LogMessageAsync($"Adding read characteristic to gatt service: description: {userDescription}, guid: {characteristicId}, value: {characteristicValue}.");

            var charactericticParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters
            {
                CharacteristicProperties = GattCharacteristicProperties.Read, 
                StaticValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(characteristicValue).AsBuffer(),
                ReadProtectionLevel = GattProtectionLevel.Plain,
                UserDescription = userDescription
            };
            
            var characteristicResult = await _gattServiceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(characteristicId, charactericticParameters);

            var readCharacteristic = characteristicResult.Characteristic;
            readCharacteristic.ReadRequested += async (a, b) =>
            {
                await _logger.LogMessageAsync("read requested..");
            }; // Warning, dont remove this...

            return characteristicResult.Error == BluetoothError.Success;
        }
```

Ive tried a couple things fix this.

- Creating a new characteristic with the same UUID to overwrite it
- Stopping the server once recieving the command, overwriting the characteristic, then starting the server again

I know this can be done, but I dont know enough of the Syntax of BLE to know where to look

Comment: Characteristic can not be advertised. You can create static characteristic with static value or set new characteristic value inside ReadRequested event handler. So a client can read new one. Or use notifications to notify client when value changed.